# Trace minimization with row norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, qcqp

For a symmetric and **negative** semidefinite matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, how can one solve the following optimization problem in tall matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \text{Trace}(X^\top Q X)\\ \text{subject to} &  \left\| x_i \right\|_2^2 \leq 1, \quad \forall i \in [n]\end{array}$$

where $x_i$ is the $i$-th row of $X$? Generally, $n \gg r$.

---

If the norm constraint is on the columns of $X$, the solution is quite [straight-forward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845443/trace-minimization-with-column-norm-constraint/3845829?noredirect=1#comment7933387_3845829). But with a constraint on the rows the problems looks much more tricky.

Comment: Could you provide some context? Why are you interested in these problems in the first place?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Of course! This problem is coming from a discretization of a functional minimization problem that I posted separately here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841616/prove-that-identity-function-is-a-global-minimum-of-a-symmetric-and-quadratic-fu . Instead of minimizing a functional $h(z): \mathbb{S}^N -> \mathbb{S}^N$, I here optimize over $h_n = h(z_i)$ where I choose $z_i$ uniformly over the sphere. In the limit of $N\to\infty$ the solution to this problem should converge to the optimal functional solution h(z).

Comment: The functional minimization problem, on the other hand, is a subproblem in a theoretical work in machine learning where we are trying to identify the solutions being learnt for a certain loss function. I am happy to provide more details offline and to include any person providing interesting insights in the acknowledgements (if they want to).

Comment: In my comment above, it should have been $h_n = h(z_n)$.